# Re-using port 443 for another service - is it possible?

Tags: port, windows-server-2003-r2

The ultimate goal is to allow a remote data connection service to operate on port 443 on a the SQL server. The application accessing the connection is behind a firewall and it is because of the client's reluctance to open another port that I have been asked to try and get this working. The current environment is Windows 2003 R2 (SP2) and SQL Server 2005. IIS is not installed, but when I try and install the third party connection software (SequeLink) it won't as it reports something is still configured on/using port 443.

Netstat does not show anything listening on the port and I've tried editing the system32\drivers\etc\services file removing any reference to port 443 and also using sc delete  to delete the HTTP and HTTPFilter (HTTP SSL in services console) services to see if this would help. Rebooting after each change.

What could still be using the port? Is what I'm trying even possible (I have my doubts but have to investigate every avenue)?

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
In case anyone comes across this in the future. Further investigation found it was a limitation of the SequeLink installation process. The installer seems to limit the port range to between 1024 and 65536. However the port used for the SLSQLServer service can be re-configured after installation. I was able to install to port 19996, then change it to 443.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered doing some port forwarding on the firewall?  Instead of opening another port you could redirect 443 for that IP on the firewall to something else on the machine (whatever port SequeLink actually wants to use) and just not fight with it?

Comment: Thanks checking into the viability of that with server locations at the moment.

Comment: Thanks again Dave. We are able to implement this in the environment that it will be hosted.